# SQL Fallback Row?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.1 with PHP and I was wondering if it would be possible to run a query that will select a specific row using the primary key, but if it doesn't exist, to return a different one.

For example: select * from table1 where id="a" else id="b"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from table1 
  where id="a"
union all
select * 
  from table1
  where id="b"
  and no exists (
    select * 
      from table1
      where id="a");
```

Comment: This actually does 3 SELECTs. It would be faster to just do a UNION between 2 SELECTS and then LIMIT 1 on the final set.

Comment: @Artem: no, because the order of UNION is not guaranteed, so the LIMIT may result in the "b" one.

Comment: Less than three select's would be a nice bonus, but still it works perfectly! Thanks =)

Comment: Remus, you might be right. In this case, you should be able to do something like this: `(SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b, ... FROM t1)
UNION
(SELECT 2 as sort_col, col2a, col2b, ... FROM t2) ORDER BY sort_col;` This is from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html.